# How to change audio frame rate in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to change audio frame from 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF) to 23.438 FPS (2048 SPF) but no luck.

code tried :

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -b:v 2000k -vcodec libx264 -x265-params keyint=50:scenecut=0 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 3.1 -r 25 -s:v 1280x720 -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -aframes 23.438 HD2_500_500.mp4
```

Error :

```
Expected int64 for frames:a
```

Comment: http://muzso.hu/2015/04/25/how-to-speed-up-slow-down-an-audio-stream-with-ffmpeg

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1DDHtC5Y8c is not ffmpeg

Comment: You can't change audio frame size for the AAC encoder - it is fixed to 1024 SPF. You can change tempo, as the given answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the audio speed using the [`​atempo`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video#Smooth) audio filter. The filter accepts exactly one parameter, the audio tempo. If not specified then the filter will assume nominal 1.0 tempo. Tempo must be in the [0.5, 100.0] range.

Here a simple example on how to speed down the audio by half:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter:a "atempo=0.5" -vn HD2_500_500.mp4
```

Comment: atempo range is 0.5-100 (older versions were limited to 0.5-2).

Comment: That true, I just made more research on the subject and found it [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo) along with the FFmpeg official Documentation, thanks.